# How to not render a false value from the database in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm working on an app that takes a boolean for subscribed or unsubscribed customers. I have a view that renders a list of customers for the admin but I do not want this list to include "unsubscribed" customers. Any ideas on how I can go about getting this done? It's an easy feature but I'm new to rails and just looking for some info.

Comment: If you are using ActiveRecord. Did you tried to use `where` method http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html ?

Comment: Please show your code for fetching the customers and your customer's database schema and maybe the loop in your view if that is relevant.

Comment: Try adding a scope in your model (`def self.subscribers; where(subscribed: true); end`) so then you can call `YourModel.subscribed` and it'll just be a collection of the subscribers that you can iterate over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to your model to filter for users who are subscribed only:

```
scope :subscribed, -> { where(subscribed: true) }
```

Then add that scope onto the method that builds your user collection:

```
@users = User.subscribed
```

These are fairly generic examples, so tailor to your classes.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord is an abstraction for your Database (SQL, i assume). Probably you have something like

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

in your controller?

Now you need to extend this to filter out the users you don't want to show:

```
def index
  @users = User.where('status = ?', 'subscribed')
end
```

(the exact query of course depends on your database table layout)